# Полиморфный доступ к членам класса в C++

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    char val = 'a';

    virtual char GetVal() {
        return val;
    }
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    char val = 'A';

    virtual char GetVal() {
        return val;
    }
}

int main() {
    Base *pb = Derived;
    std::cout << pb->val << std::endl;      //Выведет: a
    std::cout << pb->GetVal() << std::endl; //Выведет: A
    delete pb;
    return 0;
}
```

Из этого кода видно, что член с идентификатором **val** базового класса **Base** замещается другим членом с тем же идентификатором **val** в производном классе **Derived**.

В клиентском коде при использовании указателя типа **Base***, который указывает на объект типа **Derived**, доступ к открытому члену **val** объекта производного класса **Derived** мы можем получить только при использовании виртуальной функции **GetVal()**, возвращающей значение этого члена.

1. Есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ доступа к члену с именем **val** производного класса, замещающий имя члена базового класса, посредством указателя на базовый тип, не прибегая к виртуальным замещающим *get-функциям*?

Это интересно потому что, если код базового класса заменить следующим:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int val = 65; // был тип char - стал int

    virtual int GetVal() { // теперь возвращаем объект типа int
        return val;
    }
}
```

То возникает ошибка на этапе компиляции "*conflicting return type specified for 'virtual int Derived::GetVal()'*", т.к. при переопределении виртуальной функции базового класса возвращаемый ею тип должен быть таким же и в производном классе.

2. Как можно получить доступ к члену производного класса, имя которого перекрывает имя члена базового класса, но имеет другой тип, оперируя при этом указателями базового класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> способ доступа к члену с именем val производного класса, замещающий
>   имя члена базового класса

Приведение так или иначе потребуется. Т.е. нужно знать имя (ну или расположение данных) производного класса:

```
dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pb)->val; // A
```

По-хорошему, надо ещё проверять результат `dynamic_cast`а на `nullptr`.

Можно и `static_cast`, если есть уверенность в том, что `pb` указывает на экземпляр производного класса:

```
static_cast<Derived*>(pb)->val; // A
```

> получить доступ к члену производного класса, имя которого перекрывает
>   имя члена базового класса, но имеет другой тип

Точно такими же способами, как я показал выше.

Answer (score 2):

> способ доступа к **члену ... производного класса** ... посредством
>   **указателя на базовый** тип

Базовый тип **ничего не знает о производном классе**, кроме таблицы виртуальных функций.

Поэтому все решения будут так или иначе опираться на виртуальные функции или `dynamic_cast`, каковой также по сути своей является виртуальной функцией.

Comment: Тут как раз самая суть в контексте, который вы вырезали и поставили вместо него троеточия. Весь интерес в том, что имя члена базового класса перекрывается таким же именем в производном. Для функций это работает, т.к. они могут быть виртуальными, а вот для членов-данных - нет. Хотя была бы интересной возможность иметь виртуальные данные, чтобы обращаться напрямую к ним, используя динамический полиморфизм

Comment: @Дмитрий Как бы выразиться... Перефразируя - "когда я вижу `dynamic_cast`, я хватаюсь за клавиатуру". Это веревочка, которой, как многие надеются, можно привязать к велосипеду разные железки, чтобы получить красивый Харлей... По мне - это говорит о непродуманном дизайне, и менять надо именно его, потому что рано или поздно все равно к этому придет - если это что-то серьезное.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. конечная цель не указана, будем решать конкретно поставленную задачу. Для этого воспользуемся [CRTP](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/26/crtp_demystified.aspx):

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    char val = 'a';

    char GetVal() {
        return val;
    }

    auto GetDerivedVal() {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->val;
    }
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived: public Base<Derived> {
public:
    char val = 'A';

    virtual char GetVal() {
        return val;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base<Derived> *pb = new Derived;
    std::cout << pb->GetVal() << std::endl;      //Выведет: a
    std::cout << pb->GetDerivedVal() << std::endl; //Выведет: A
    delete pb;
    return 0;
}
```

Не знаю, подойдёт ли Вам это для реального применения, но задачу из вопроса это решает.

---

Если же необходим динамизм, то с некоторыми условиями(мы заранее знаем все типы, которые нам нужны) и воспользовавшись `boost::variant`, мы можем сделать следующее:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
using Variant = boost::variant<char, int>;
class Base {
public:
    char val = 'a';

    virtual Variant GetVal() {
        return val;
    }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    int val = 'A';

    Variant GetVal() override {
        return val;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base *pa = new Base;
    Base *pb = new Derived;
    std::cout << pa->GetVal() << std::endl;      //Выведет: a
    std::cout << pb->GetVal() << std::endl; //Выведет: 65
    delete pb;
    delete pa;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что в данном коде нет никакого полиморфного поведения, т.к. указатель pb уже имеет конкретный тип **Base<Derived>** на этапе компиляции, т.е. такой указатель может работать только с объектами типа **Derived**. Смысл всего этого, если можно явно создать указатель типа  *Derived**?

Comment: @Дмитрий, в Вашем вопрос чётко написано: _не прибегая к виртуальным замещающим get-функциям?_. Тогда о каком полиморфном поведение можно говорить, если Вы явно просите не использовать виртуальные функции, которые являются единственным способом реализации полиморфизма в C++?

Comment: А что, если тип объекта не известен на этапе компиляции, как, например, в коллекции объектов, которые могут быть Base и Derived типами, и работа с которыми осуществляется через указатели базового типа?

Comment: @Дмитрий, никак. Если только не создавать виртуальную функцию, которая будет возвращать что-то типа `boost::any`, а потом уже оттуда вытаскивать значение. Но для этого нужно будет знать, что лежит в `any`, а это уже не подходит — динамизм нужен. Можно конечно ограничить набор возможных типов и использовать `boost::variant`, но непонятно, что за задача реально стоит перед Вами, поэтому я и не могу сказать, подойдёт ли решение.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы давали ссылку на статью, в которой это имеет смысл только в том случае, если такие объекты передаются в функцию, которая является **шаблонной**: template<typename Impl> void executeCrtp(CrtpBase<Impl>& crtp, const std::vector<unsigned>& indicies). Тут как раз можно говорить о статическом полиморфизме

Comment: @Дмитрий, статический полиморфизм это условность. Реально, под полиморфизмом всегда понимается динамический, если не оговорено обратное. Сейчас добавлю пример с `boost::variant`

Answer (score 0):

Функции не могут отличаться только возвращаемым параметром, как альтернативу, преобразовать немного виртуальный метод

```
class Base {
public:
    char val = 'a';

    virtual void GetVal(char &_char) {
        _char = val;
    }

    virtual void GetVal(int &_int) = 0;
 };

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int val = 65; // был тип char - стал int

    virtual void GetVal(int &_int) { // теперь возвращаем объект типа int
       _int = val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *pb = new Derived;

    char myChar;
    int myInt;

    pb->GetVal(myChar);
    pb->GetVal(myInt);

    std::cout << myChar << std::endl;      //Выведет: a
    std::cout << myInt << std::endl; //Выведет: A
    delete pb;
    return 0;
}
```

Но лучше бы разобраться для чего это нужно. Мне кажется можно найти другой подход

Answer (score 0):

1. `dynamic_cast`. Но это уже наводит на сомнения по поводу дизайна.
2. Виртуальное замещение будет лишь для совпадающей сигнатуры
   метода. Иначе - перекрытие. Доставать тоже только кастом.

Comment: А разве возвращаемое значение относится к **сигнатуре** метода?

Comment: @Дмитрий, вы правы, в общем к сигнатуре не относится, но при override решает. : _"The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the classes of the functions"_